# How to get week day of persian calendar in java

Tags: android, calendar, persian, persian-calendar

I want to set up a function to get the first day and the last day of the Persian year and display it in a list for weeks, and do it with a Gregorian date to pass to the function.
I want to use this code on Android Studios.
Please Help me.

> Example

```
    public class Week {
        public String start_date;
        public String end_date;
    }
    public list<Week> GetWeek(Date date) {
      //return list 

      //   start_date = 1396-01-01 ;
      //  end_date = 1396-01-07;

      //......
      // And by the end of the year like that
    }
```

I also used the Persian Calendar library, but it does not work in the loop

> Code

```
CurrentPersianDate = new PersianDate();
        NextPersianDate = new PersianDate();

        CurrentPersianDate.setShYear(1396);
        CurrentPersianDate.setShDay(1);
        CurrentPersianDate.setShMonth(1);

        NextPersianDate.setShYear(1397);
        NextPersianDate.setShDay(1);
        NextPersianDate.setShMonth(1);

        while (CurrentPersianDate.before(NextPersianDate)) {
            CurrentPersianDate.addWeek(1);
            LOG(CurrentPersianDate.getShYear() + " " + CurrentPersianDate.getShMonth() + " " +
            CurrentPersianDate.getShDay() , "");
        }
```

Comment: Use [PersianCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @FortyTwo I Updated post please check again.thanks